# Return value of process to String

Tags: scala, exec, system, wget

I'm attempting to return the source of a page using the wget command to String using command :

```
val url: String = "https://morningconsult.com/alert/house-passes-employee-stock-options-bill-aimed-startups/"
import sys.process._
val result: String = ("wget -qO- " + url !).toString
println("result : " + result);
```

but return value is 0. This is output of code :

```
result : 0
```

How to access the return value of `wget` in a variable , in this case the source value of the url ?

Comment: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilder@!!:String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`!` returns the exit code of the process (`0` in your case). If you need the output of the process you should use `!!` instead:

```
val url = "https://morningconsult.com/alert/house-passes-employee-stock-options-bill-aimed-startups/"
import sys.process._
val result = ("wget -qO- " + url !!).toString
println("result : " + result)
```

([relevant documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilder@!!:String))